# Live Linux Distro for text only mode

Tags: linux, text, live, mode, cd

I'm looking for a linux distro where I can boot into it via USB, run a script on startup and shutdown. I need bare minimum, but I also need network drivers. Also need to save files across reboots.

I've looked into DamnSmallLinux with networking. Are there any other options? Fastest boot is preferred. I don't need mouse, sound, etc. Bare minimum for fast booting. To save files across reboots, should I create a USB with two partitions and save to the non OS partition? I would have to mount this partition in the OS?

Comment: This is off topic here, why not try SuperUser instead?

Comment: @H2CO3 - would get rejected from SU because it's a shopping and recommendation question, which as you know are verboten. Also question was cross-posted, in future please just flag, don't encourage users to repeat their question on another SE site.

Comment: @H2CO3 - cool, see my edit as well :)

Comment: Sorry. As you can tell I'm new to all of this. I see that reputation is something to maintain. I wasn't sure what category this would have fit into. @Kev the question hasn't been rejected from SU. If you have a recommendation of where to post a question like this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @TheWino - unfortunately shopping and recommendation questions aren't on topic anywhere on the SE network, see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ - because they encourage answers that devolve into a list "point-in-time" favourites that don't stand up to the test of time. You could earn some Q&A rep (just 20) then pop into one of the many chat rooms (such as http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/26/unix-and-linux) and ask for this kind of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.slitaz.org/en/

the best compromise that i know between a tiny distribution and an usable and compact system.